# API to Get All Tasks to be Executed in the Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way of getting the order of all tasks running in a build pipeline. As we are building a pipeline decorator, we want to know if there is a way to check if the pipeline has specific tasks. We tried using the timeline api but it will only display all jobs and tasks that have been executed or currently executing. As we are executing the pipeline decorator at the start, we want to get all tasks to be executed in the pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't such an API to get all tasks to be executed (including the decorator ones) directly in Azure DevOps Pipeline.

However we can get the order of all tasks running from the logs of a build pipeline by calling the [Get Build Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20logs?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) REST API, and then calling the [Get Build Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20log?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) REST API to get the specific task log to get the specific task name. It will also include the auto-injected decorator tasks.

But it has the reverse order from the response. For example,in below screenshot the task showed in `log1` is the last task running in the pipeline.

[image]

Comment: Hello Andy - I would really like to have a way to get all the tasks during the start of execution.  One example is when I need to check if the unit tests or functional tests exist in a pipeline.  Since pipeline jobs can have dependencies, I cannot fail the build right away since I have to wait before the job starts to execute so I can get the tasks via log/timeline api.  I can get it the hard way by getting the tasks from the build pipeline definition but it can get really challenging when the pipeline definition uses YAML.

Comment: Currently we don't have such a way to achieve the requirement. From the build pipeline definition we can only get the pipeline settings, but cannot get the order of the tasks. Since we can set [depends on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#yaml-basics) and [Specify conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to adjust the order sometimes.

Comment: @CarterJordan Is the reply helpful for you? Any update here?